# Linux System Administrator Guide?

Tags: linux

i am an CS student and i got an job-offer as an Linux Administrator.
I took this job to get deeper into Linux in order to understand and use Linux more wise.

So : 
Do you have any suggestions (books,links) to Linux System Administration.
For Example : installing software over ssh , creating a mailinglist, installing and maintaining lampp. etc?

Comment: http://www.theregister.co.uk/odds/bofh/ -- All you'll ever need to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like [The linux Documentation Project](http://www.tldp.org) for basic information. Although the entry I go to most on that site is [The Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html). I've also found that google is your friend when it comes to man pages `man <command>` in google will generally give you a very well formatted man page which is useful in keeping the number of open terminals down.

Comment: I've found Greg's wiki (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/) is infinitely better than The Advanced Bash Scripting Guide.

Answer (score 3):

I know that you asked for books, but since you desire to learn...

One of the best learning tools that you'll find is a good virtual machine manager, such as VMWare or VirtualBox. You can set up a complete virtual learning environment right on your pc, and experiment without the worry of making a mistake in a production environment.

.

Answer (score 2):

There are good books on specific topics, and good books on basic stuff (in both cases, check out [O'Reilly](http://oreilly.com/store/complete.html) books), but there's nothing that I'm aware of that is a comprehensive middle ground.

IMO, your best bet is to learn by doing anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As well as linux nitty gritty,I think getting meta about system administration is not just useful, but needed.

Technical knowledge is needed, but soft skills, organizational and operational context and processes place it in perspective.

try Mark Burgess' ["Principles of System and Network Admnistration"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471823031)

and

Tom Limoncelli's ["Practice of System and Network Administration, Second Edition"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321492668)

Answer (score 1):

I can very highly recommend the [Linux Administration Handbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131480049).

Also, see the answers to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1046/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-sysadmin-should-read).

And commit the contents of [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/EnglishFrontPage) to memory.

Answer (score 1):

I learned a lot from the [Debian Reference](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/index.en.html) when I was starting out long ago. While some sections are Debian-specific and it of course uses Debian file paths and conventions, a lot of the information is very general. It covers everything from authentication, to network services, to backups, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[How Linux Works](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593270356) on No Starch Press is a fantastic introduction to Linux administration.

Answer (score 0):

I keep the following two books on my shelf. When new editions come out I buy them.

Essential System Administration by Frisch; O'Reilly

Running Linux by Dalheimer;et.al.; O'Reilly

The Frisch book covers more than Linux.  Multiple Unix variants are covered.

---

Unix Shell Programming by Kochan; Sams

Is adequate.  Somebody may have a better candidate for shell scripting.

Comment: To heck with shell scripting.  Perl FTW!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the "Unleashed" series by SAMS, personally.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the [how2forge](http://www.howtoforge.com/) for basic lamp functions

or maybe if Redhat/Centos/fedora is your thing [RHCT/e](http://www.redhat.com/certification/rhce/)

or maybe a Comptia [Linux+](http://www.comptia.org/certifications/listed/linux.aspx)

don't really know what your background is so basically throwing certs at you (sorry I know you asked for books etc)

Comment: A RHCE is nice, but I don't think that he/she can afford it.

Answer (score -1):

[Linux from Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) will teach you everything you wanted to know about Linux, and the stuff you were too afraid to ask about.