# Debian 6 home server

Tags: linux, debian, imap, email-server

I need some help to get started. I've been trying and trying to get everything working for my home server.

What I want is a guide to install all this:

- LAMP (and the additions to this like phpmyadmin)
- SSH,
- Mail (I have a domain, I want webui, spamprotection, antivirus),
- FTP,
- SVN,
- LDAP (possibly)
- System monitoring
- System security
- POP / IMAP
- Filesharing with mac / pc

I'd love a book, or an online tutorial, but I've searched a lot and tried several guides without good results.

I managed to get LAMP, SSH, sendmail, SVN, FTP working, however I cant receive mail, LDAP, monitor anything, I can say that I got very much security, POP/IMAP, or fileshare.

However I managed to get IMAP working, in sense that the server receive the email, but I cannot access them.

And furthermost, I need to have a good way to control this, like an webui to control the server, although I use ssh a lot, I'd like some way to get an overview.

Comment: Read a good book on Debian administration

Comment: Sounds like you need up to ten books, especially if some of the areas you mentioned are completely new to you. Personally I've read several excellent books published by O'Reilly.

Comment: Yes, 10 books and possibly more. Some of those topics, like running a mail server, could easily be a couple of books. The O'Reilly animal book series is a good start.

Comment: Ok, so why is this off topic? I didn't post this question here. However, yes great advice, and I'd love to read these O'Reilly books. I'll check them out and see what I find.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/1144/984 - UNIX and Linux System Administration Handbook - 4th Edition

Comment: Your question was extremely broad.  There are a large number of questions on this site that cover detail that would get you started.  Start here for a list of links to some of the better questions.  http://serverfault.com/questions/9766/what-a-beginner-should-know-learn-for-sysadmin-job

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Webmin when you want to use a webui for configuring your server. Most of the needed configs you can do in there. 
Concerning your other query, you're doing a lot in once, just do everything one after the other and take your time. When you sort all out (most things can be found on the internet) all will work fine.
Goodluck!

Comment: I wouldn't even recommend webmin to a ravenous bugblatter beast of traal's grandmother.

Comment: I don't see a better alternative in your comment tough Tom.

Comment: @Ezeyme No self-respecting Sysadmin would ever use/install webmin. You do not need an alternative. Learn how to use your terminal.

Comment: @Bart; thank you for your comment. As I know, I am a (self-respecting) Linux Systadmin :) But Oldek asked for a webui to control the server, that's the reason for my answer. (Bit pity that Tom didn't get that).