# Got root, now how should I configure my server?

Tags: vps

I've been a developer for years and by trade I had to know a little bit of server side configuration. But now I find myself needing to manage my own VPS instance (Amazon EC2) and I'm lost. I'd like to know what are the common ways to configure an Apache and MySQL server that is secure and efficient.

For example right now I'm doing everything as root but I doubt that's the best way at all. My whole Apache is configured to serve 1 site when I'd like it to be able to serve multiple sites.

Where do I start?

Comment: Try to stick to one question at a time and keep them narrow enough that they won't fill an entire book.  Pick one of the "should I be root" or "Apache vhosts" questions and split them into two.  If you're looking to become a full time sysadmin, [this question would be a good place to start](http://serverfault.com/questions/1046/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-sysadmin-should-read).

Comment: Ladadadada thanks but while I understand your remark my question is really broad in its nature. Frank understood it with his answer which contains very good pointers for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to know some basic Bash commands, you can find them here:

http://maketecheasier.com/basic-bash-command-for-new-linux-users/2008/01/22

Here is another tutorial for LAMP(Linux,Apache,MySQL,PHP).....
http://www.lamphowto.com/

Basic Apache website(Virtual hosting) configuration:
http://www.linode.com/wiki/index.php/Configure_apache_to_use_virtual_hosts_on_ubuntu_server
http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2008/01/09/setting-up-name-based-virtual-hosting/

and for MySQL

http://library.linode.com/databases/mysql/ubuntu-10.04-lucid