# Backup/recover Dell PERC RAID controller configuration?

Tags: backup, dell, dell-perc

I have a Dell server with the disks in RAID 10, using the PERC RAID controller in the server.  I maintain the data data on the drives, but I'm worried about what would happen if there was an error with the disk controller or the configuration of the drives.

I read that the controller configuration is copied to the disks by default, but when I delete the configuration from the controller and try to retrieve it I can't.

Does anyone know how to backup the disk configuration for a Dell PERC RAID card, or recover it form the disks if it's been damaged or erased form the controller?

Comment: RAID != Backup. Backup the operating system, applications, etc. running on the server.

Comment: @joeqwerty RAID  for Maintain not backup true , I meant how to mange the server so I can protect it when ant failure occur . are recommend me to read any article /books? thanks

Comment: Search for Tom Lemoncelli on the 'Net. Visit a bookstore.

Comment: You may want to start here: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1986/what-are-the-canonical-answers-weve-discovered-over-the-years http://serverfault.com/questions/1046/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-sysadmin-should-read

Comment: I echo what everyone else has said about needing proper backups, but the question of how to backup or recover the disk configuration for a RAID controller card, so I've edited and reopened your question.

Comment: I have modified the question why the down vote

Comment: It had that downvote before, when the question was kind of unintelligible.

Answer (score 2):

> but when I delete the configuration from the controller and try to retrieve it I can't

Did you perform this configuration deletion while the disks were still seated? If so, this does not simulate the config "going missing" from the controller - this action actually clears the config from the controller *and* from the drives.

To test this accurately, you'd need to remove the disks before clearing the config on the controller. Then reboot with the drives re-added, and you should get a prompt regarding a "foreign" configuration having been detected on the drives.

In answer to your question, no - you cannot create a backup of the RAID configuration using any functionality built-in to the controller. The config is saved to both controller and each disk, and it *should* never go missing from all the drives unless you explicitly delete it (which includes "clearing" a foreign config - something that numerous people mistakenly do in an attempt to recover before contacting support).

Trust the controller to do its job with saving the configuration internally and to the drives. Trying to go further than that is focusing on the wrong risks. If you experience an issue that leaves you with a completely missing or corrupt RAID config on the drives, your recovery plan should involve a full validated backup of the data on the virtual disk. Anything else would be straying far from industry standard best-practices, and even farther from wisdom.

Answer (score 1):

If you switch for a same controller the configuration the disk got will be use, then if you switch a disk in the raid, then the controller will re-built. You can't make a copy, to switch on another controller platform at all. And you must note where your disk was placed (slot 0, etc..)

Make a full acronis/ghost, or those kind of image of your volume, and restore it to another controller/disk is the good way to do it.